# Metric for predictor of stochastic variables with only 1 sample

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

**Situation/Question**
I have a set of stochastic variables $S_X=\{X_i | i \in 1..n\}$. $X_i$ can take on either $1$ or $0$ as value. Both $P(X_i=1)$ and $P(X_i=0)$ are unknown but we have a model $M$ that makes a prediction for $P(X_i=1)$ being $\hat{P}_M(X_i=1)$.

I'm trying to find a metric to evaluate how accurate my model's predictions are. The tricky part is that I only have $1$ sample for each stochastic variable $X_i$.

**My approach** 
My first approach was to try and get more samples by dividing $S_X$ into classes based on the prediction made by $M$. The assumption being that if I have a class defined by the subset $I$ (of $1..n$) for which:

- All chances in $\{\hat{P}_M(X_i=1) | i \in I\}$ are roughly equal to a constant $c$
- This constant $c$ is roughly equal to the expected value (approximated by the samples) of $\{X_i | i \in I\}$.
  (In math notation $\frac{\sum_{i \in I} X_i}{size(I)} \approx c$)

But this method can fail fairly easily. Take for example $P(X_k=1)=0.8$, $P(X_l=1)=0.2$ and $M$'s predictions $\hat{P}_M(X_k=1)=0.5$, $\hat{P}_M(X_l=1)=0.5$. Using the method above I would conclude $M$ is very accurate while it is clearly not.

I'm now starting to doubt if what I'm asking is even possible or if I need some extra information. Is my initial approach the best possible? How would you solve this problem?

Comment: If $\hat{P}_M(X_k=1)=0.5,\hat{P}_M(X_l=1)=0.5$ and similarly for others then your model is not really helping.  You might want to look at [scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule)

Comment: @Henry Thanks I will look into this. And $\hat{P}_M(X_k=1)=0.5, \hat{P}_M(X_l=1)=0.5$ can be correct (if that is the underlying distribution), could you elaborate why the model wouldn't be helping then?

Comment: There is no skill needed to create a model which always predicts $\hat{P}_M(X_k=1)=0.5$ and $\hat{P}_M(X_k=0)=0.5$ and no meaningful way of testing its skill with a single observation, whether the actual probability is $0.5$ is correct or not.